# How to redirect debug output line by line into text file after playbook execution

Tags: ansible

How to redirect debug output line by line into text file after playbook execution.

```
- name: Copy content to the output file ====> ( redirecting output variable i.e.  paths to a file.)
  copy:
      content: "{{ paths }}"  
      dest:"/home/oracle/script_results/{{inventory_hostname}}_get_facts.txt"
```

Getting this output in one line..

```
[u'/u01/oracle/Oracle_Home/abc.txt', u'/u01/oracle/Oracle_Home/oracle.jar', u'/u01/oracle/Oracle_Home/oracle.war', u'/u01/oracle/Oracle_Home/oracle.ear', u'/u01/oracle/Oracle_Home/xyz.ear'
```

,.........contd.

Answer (score 1):

**Ansible strategy, with Callback Plugin**

You can use the **log_play** plugin

This is the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/log_plays.html

> This callback writes playbook output to a file per host in the /var/log/ansible/hosts directory

You need to whitelist it in the `ansible.cfg` and here is the documentation on how to do it: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#enabling-callback-plugins

**BASH strategy**

Or you can use bash to redirec ansible output:

```
ansible-playbook ... | tee -a ansible_log_file.log
```

The command `tee` will display the output to the stdout and save it to file